# Parsing an UTF-8 Encodded XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML File containing some Arabic Characters retrieved from a URL so I had to encode it in UTF-8 so it can handle such characters.

XML File:

```
<Entry>

    <lstItems>            
           <item>
        <id>1</id>
            <title>News Test 1</title>
            <subtitle>16/7/2012</subtitle>
        <img>joelle.mobi-mind.com/imgs/news1.jpg</img>
           </item>
           <item>
        <id>2</id>
            <title>كريم</title>
            <subtitle>16/7/2012</subtitle>
        <img>joelle.mobi-mind.com/imgs/news2.jpg</img>
           </item>
           <item>
        <id>3</id>
            <title>News Test 333</title>
            <subtitle>16/7/2012</subtitle>
        <img>joelle.mobi-mind.com/imgs/news3.jpg</img>
           </item> 
           <item>
        <id>4</id>
            <title>ربيع</title>
            <subtitle>16/7/2012</subtitle>
        <img>joelle.mobi-mind.com/imgs/cont20.jpg</img>
           </item> 
           <item>
        <id>5</id>
            <title>News Test 55555</title>
            <subtitle>16/7/2012</subtitle>
        <img>joelle.mobi-mind.com/imgs/cont21.jpg</img>
           </item>      
           <item>
        <id>6</id>
            <title>News Test 666666</title>
            <subtitle>16/7/2012</subtitle>
        <img>joelle.mobi-mind.com/imgs/cont22.jpg</img>
           </item>               
    </lstItems>
  </Entry>
```

I parsed the XML retrieved from a URL it as String as shown below:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {

    try {
        return new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //String xml = null;
                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    xml = new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).getBytes(),"UTF-8");


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return xml;




            }
        }.execute(url).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml;
}
```

Now the returned String is passed to this method to get a Document for later use as shown below:

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){

        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            StringReader xmlstring=new StringReader(xml);
            is.setCharacterStream(xmlstring);
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
                    //Code Stops here !
            doc = db.parse(is); 


        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        // return DOM
        return doc;

}
```

an Error ocured with this message:

```
09-18 07:51:40.441: E/Error:(1210): Unexpected token (position:TEXT ï»¿@1:4 in java.io.StringReader@4144c240)
```

So the code crashes where I showed above with the following Error

```
09-18 07:51:40.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.university1/com.example.university1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Kindly note that the code works fine with ISO encoding.

Comment: Upvoted simply because there was two downvotes without comments (and without any apparent reason, the question is legitimate).

Answer (score 2):

You've added a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your UTF-8 file. Which is bad.

Maybe you edited your file with Notepad, or maybe you should check your editor to ensure it doesn't add a BOM.

As the BOM seems to be inside the text and not at start, you also need to remove it by using the delete key around its position (it's invisible in most editors). This may have happened during a file concatenation operation.

Comment: Sorry but why is a BOM bad? Is usefull to detect UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: It was created to detect Byte Order in other Unicode formats but was extended by Microsoft to UTF-8 where it doesn't make sense. It creates weird bugs when, for example, you concatenate files.

Comment: so what do you suggest me to do @dystroy

Comment: 1) check the settings in your editors to ensure they don't write a BOM. 2) go to position 1:4 of your file and remove a few chars around to remove those hidden chars.

Comment: I edited this line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to <?xml version="1.0"?> and it didn't work

Comment: What dystroy meant was you have to delete the Byte Order Mark (BOM), which is invisible in some Editors. The "encoding" attribute can be left untouched.

Comment: But there was a BOM at start. Never use Notepad for coding. I you use another code editor, check it doesn't write a BOM.

Comment: well the the code did not cash but the arabic text is not displayed correctly some weird characters are displayed instead

Comment: Did you put `encoding="UTF-8"` back ? There was no need to remove it.

Comment: am sorry am new to XML can you first recomend a gd XML editor second can you tell me exactly what a DOM is and how u removed it

Comment: @dystroy what exactly did u do to the file ?

Comment: @dystroy i did put UTF-8 and still the characters are not arabic, weird characters instead

Comment: A BOM is a Byte Order Mark. It is (can be) used in Unicode-encoded files (for example UTF-16) to make clear, which encoding exactly the file is in (least significant byte first or most significant ... ). For UTF-8 however, this does not make sense, because there is only one byte order in UTF 8. That's why everybody except Microsoft just drops that BOM. Java uses UTF16 by default, afaik. _D_OM is "Document Object Model" and has nothing to do with encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @Fildor On the contrary, using a BOM in UTF-8 encoded text does indeed make sense when used as a flag to identify the content is encoded as UTF-8. Embedding the BOM is a workaround for our file systems lacking the metadata of file encoding. This use of a BOM in UTF-8 is explained in the very Wikipedia page you linked. That page discusses the pros and cons. This meme of “no BOM in UTF-8” persistently floats around the internet, but is simply incorrect. Learn the pros and cons, and decide for yourself when a BOM in UTF-8 is beneficial to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the problem, but `EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).getBytes()` is using the default platform encoding. You should use `EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)` as the `String`, no need to turn it into bytes.

Also, read this http://kunststube.net/encoding/ for useful background on what's going on.

Comment: Thanx for the help but its not the issue here

Comment: @Karim `new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).getBytes(),"UTF-8");` WILL MANGLE YOUR CHARACTERS if your platform encoding is not UTF-8

Comment: tried it , the characters are weird not the arabic characters in the XML!

Comment: getBytes() is using ISO-8859-1, not the platform encoding

Comment: @njzk2 the javadoc of `java.lang.String.getBytes()` says "Encodes this `String` into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset"