# Malformed Arabic in HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, xml, utf-8, httprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing an UTF-8 Encodded XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472999/parsing-an-utf-8-encodded-xml-file)

I am parsing a UTF-8 Encoded XML file which contains some arabic characters everything else is working properly except that the arabic characters are not displayed, some weird characters are displayed as below:

```
ÙØ±ÙÙ
```

here is the link to the XML "http://212.12.165.44:7201/UniNews121.xml" file am Parsing

below is the code

```
        public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {

        try {
            return new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    //String xml = null;
                    try {

                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET,"UTF-8");
                        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        xml = new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).getBytes(),"UTF-8");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                                    //just to remove the BOM Element    
                    xml=xml.substring(3);

            //Here am printing the xml and the arabic chars are malformed                                                       
                                    Log.i("DEMO", xml);
                    return xml;

                }
            }.execute(url).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

Kindly note that no errors are occurring and everything is working properly just the arabic chars are malformed.

**I would appreciate your help but please be specific in your answers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
xml = new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity).getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

doesn't do what you want. `EntityUtils.toString()` uses the default charset, then you call getBytes(), which uses platform encoding as well when no encoding is specified, then you call new String, which tries to read this byte[] as an UTF-8 string byte[].

You simply need to call

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: thanks man it worked at this stage but now am facing another issue

Comment: 09-18 13:18:21.022: E/Error:(3750): Unexpected token (position:TEXT xml version="1.0...@2:1 in java.io.StringReader@41449a58) 
when i do this 
StringReader xmlstring=new StringReader(xml);
   is.setCharacterStream(xmlstring);
   is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
   doc = db.parse(is);

Comment: i don't see what `is` is here, nor why would you use a StringReader on an xml String. I suggest you post a new question for this

Comment: ok i will link you the new question